# Is using correlated subquery better than join? (indexing perspective)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing, subquery

I read somewhere something like this:

> Indexes will be used per queries.

So as you know, this is **two queries**:

```
SELECT m1.*, (SELECT 1 FROM mytable2 m2 WHERE col2 = ?) AS sth
FROM mytable1 m1 WHERE col1 = ?
```

Well query above can use two indexes: `mytable1(col1)`, `mytable2(col2)`. Because of being two separated queries.

Now take a look at this one: *(the same as previous query, just uses `join` instead of subquery)*

```
SELECT m1.*, m2.1 AS sth
FROM mytable1 m1
JOIN mytable2 m2 ON m2.col2 = ?
WHERE m1.col1 = ?
```

But this ^ query, is just **one query**. So it can use just one index. Is my understanding right? So using subquery is better for indexing, right?

Comment: The use of the index  is evaluated  by the query optimizer  engine and  work also with joined  table ..

Comment: Rewrite the example to avoid the pitfalls described in the answers.  Then provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ... ` for each.  Then we can discuss what you _intended_ to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this ^ query, is just one query. So it can use just one index. Is my understanding right? So using subquery is better for indexing, right?

You misunderstand. MySQL can use one index **per table reference**.

So in this case, it can use both indexes: mytable1(col1), mytable2(col2).

You can even use two different indexes from the *same* table, if you do a self-join or a UNION or a subquery. Each time you reference the table counts as a separate table reference.

```
SELECT m1.*, m2.1 AS sth
FROM mytable1 m1
JOIN mytable2 m2 ON m2.col2 = ?
WHERE m1.col1 = ?
```

Regardless of indexing, this is a strange query. You have no condition that relates mytable1 to mytable2. So you're doing a Cartesian product between the two tables. One or both table may be selecting a single row, depending on your conditions for col1 and col2. But it's still a Cartesian product, so if the conditions on both tables return multiple rows, you'll get result set with a lot of repetition.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

The two queries are different, in multiple respects:

- The first returns all rows in `mytable1` that match the `where` condition, regardless of whether there is a match in the second table.  The second only returns rows that match.
- The first fails with an error if the subquery returns more than one row.  The second returns multiple rows that match.
- As a consequence, the first could return `NULL` for `sth`, the second cannot.

My advice is to first learn to write the query that meets your functional needs.  Then worry about performance.

As for your question, both correlated subqueries and joins can make use of an index.  The idea that correlated subqueries are *always* worse than joins is an old-wives' tale (no offense to old wives) that should be forgotten.

Comment: Thank you .. but your explanation is all about the difference between my two queries .. Ok I got it, I couldn't emulate a join according to a subquery correctly. But what about indexing? subquery uses a better index or join?

Comment: @MartinAJ: MySQL can make effective use of indexes in either case. As Gordon says, the two queries return fundamentally *different* results, which may happen to be the same under special conditions.  With the subquery in the SELECT list, the query will throw an error if the subquery returns more than one row. In the join query, if no rows are found in `m2`, the query won't return any rows. **First** define what result you want return, under what conditions. Is `col2` guranteed to be UNIQUE?. (And for Gordon, +10, running the risk of offending old wives.)

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . Your two queries are *different*.  One suits the needs and answers the question that needs to be answered.  That is the one you should use.  After getting the query correct, you can address performance, if that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it all depends. At the end of the day, SQL Server will create execution plans, and depending on how it interprets your query, one might be better than the other. Having that said, generally, join is better.